# How do I resolve this H10 error on Heroku from my nodejs/postgress and react project

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

Please help. I keep getting this H10 error when I deploy my PERN project on Heroku. I suspect the error may be coming from postgres as the logs seem to say but I am out of ideas. I have set the port to "process.env.PORT" as most suggestions say and config variables are on Heroku .
here is my server.js

````
    const http = require('http');
    const app = require('./app');
    const db = require('./db/db.js')
    
    db.authenticate() 
      .then(()=>{console.log('connected successfully')
      main()
    })
      
    
      .catch(error =>(console.log(error)))
    
    
    
    const main = async () => {
    const normalizePort = val => {
      const port = parseInt(val, 10);
    
      if (isNaN(port)) {
        return val;
      }
      if (port >= 0) {
        return port;
      }
      return false;
    };
    const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8000');
    app.set('port', port);
    
    const errorHandler = error => {
      if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
      }
      const address = server.address();
      const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 'port: ' + port;
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
          console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges.');
          process.exit(1);
          break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
          console.error(bind + ' is already in use.');
          process.exit(1);
          break;
        default:
          throw error;
      }
    };
    
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    
    server.on('error', errorHandler);
    server.on('listening', () => {
      const address = server.address();
      const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 'port ' + port;
      console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
    });
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build")));
    
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build', 'index.html'));
    });
    
    server.listen(port);  
    }
    
and my app.js
    
    ```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const postRoutes = require('./routes/post');
    const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
    const path = require('path');
    const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
    ```
    
    //app.use(express.json());
    
    
     app.use(bodyparser.json())
     app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
    
    
    
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
        next();
      });   
    
     
    app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
    app.use('/api/posts', postRoutes);
    app.use('/api/auth', userRoutes);
    
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if(req.url.includes("/images/")){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "images/picture.png"))
      }
      console.log(req.url)
      next()
    })
    
    
    module.exports = app;
````

my heroku logs:

```
     »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.60.1.
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248770+00:00 app[web.1]: triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248770+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248770+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248771+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248772+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._connectionCallback (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:130:24)
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248772+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248773+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorEvent (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248773+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (node:events:526:28)
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248773+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.reportStreamError (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248774+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248774+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248774+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248775+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248775+00:00 app[web.1]: parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248775+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248775+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248776+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248776+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248776+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248776+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248776+00:00 app[web.1]: },
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248777+00:00 app[web.1]: original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248777+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248777+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248777+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248778+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248778+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248778+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248778+00:00 app[web.1]: }
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.248779+00:00 app[web.1]: }
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.473441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2022-04-08T05:53:25.545533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2022-04-08T11:21:39.958520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2022-04-08T11:21:49.686507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
    2022-04-08T11:21:50.907291+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2022-04-08T11:21:50.907304+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
    2022-04-08T11:21:50.907304+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
    2022-04-08T11:21:50.907304+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291113+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291123+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._connectionCallback (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:130:24)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291123+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291124+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorEvent (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291125+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (node:events:526:28)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291126+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.reportStreamError (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291126+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291127+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291127+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291128+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291128+00:00 app[web.1]: parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291128+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291129+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291129+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291129+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291130+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291131+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291131+00:00 app[web.1]: },
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291131+00:00 app[web.1]: original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291132+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291132+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291132+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291132+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291133+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291133+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291133+00:00 app[web.1]: }
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291134+00:00 app[web.1]: }
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291954+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/process/promises:279
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291956+00:00 app[web.1]: triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291957+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291957+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291957+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291958+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._connectionCallback (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:130:24)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291958+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291959+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorEvent (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291959+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (node:events:526:28)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291959+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.reportStreamError (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291959+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291960+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291960+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291960+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291961+00:00 app[web.1]: parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291961+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291961+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291962+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291962+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291962+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291962+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291963+00:00 app[web.1]: },
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291963+00:00 app[web.1]: original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291963+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291963+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291964+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291964+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291964+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291964+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291964+00:00 app[web.1]: }
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.291965+00:00 app[web.1]: }
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.453104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2022-04-08T11:21:51.661389+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2022-04-08T13:41:28.066268+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=socialapp400.herokuapp.com request_id=6e193689-d520-4a3b-b74f-3f57fbb98240 fwd="41.90.63.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-04-08T13:41:37.732157+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api" host=socialapp400.herokuapp.com request_id=dae9e423-59d3-4124-b8fa-d8983e1ecfbf fwd="41.90.63.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2022-04-08T14:11:40.368593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=socialapp400.herokuapp.com request_id=2eae5ca8-4b92-46f0-b223-d6e973b4f249 fwd="41.90.63.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: my Heroku logs:

Comment: Please [edit] your logs into your question.

Comment: Your database won't be on the local machine on Heroku. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55809372/354577, for example

Comment: Hey Chris could you break  it down more for me? What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: You need to stop trying to connect to your database on `127.0.0.1` and instead use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable that Heroku Postgres provides. I'm guessing that's in your `db/db.js` file. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database

Comment: Thank you @Chris . Using DATABASE_URL solved my issue. Since I am using sequelize I had to use this : `  const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
  const db  = new Sequelize( process.env.DATABASE_URL,{
    dialectOptions:{
      ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      }
    }
  }  )`